# Adding some parameter check while calling and starting new service intent

Tags: java, android

I started learning java and android app development recently. I made a project with a lots of help from stackoverflow and it was working fine untill someone cracked it and bypassed the login activity class.

So all I want to know that is their any method that i can add while starting new service in code "section A" so that when my called service loads, it checks if it was called by the code in "section A", it will run only then else it will close the app.

**Section A**

```
......
Toast.makeText(context, "Login Successfull\n" + ss[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
btnLogin.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
alertDialog.dismiss();
context.startService(new Intent(context, Loader.class));
}

else
if (test.contains(sekkrr))
{
String lg = test;
String[]ss;
ss = lg.split("\\@@");
ss = ss[1].split("\\@@");
Toast.makeText(context, "Welcome Back User \n" + ss[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
btnLogin.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
alertDialog.dismiss();
context.startService(new Intent(context, Loader.class));
}
else if (test.contains("keyhasexpired"))
......

......
```

**Service Called**

```
....
public class Loader extends Service {
    //********** Here you can easly change the menu appearance **********//
    public static final String TAG = "Mod_Menu"; //Tag for logcat 
    
    int TEXT_SETTINGS = Color.RED;
    int HintTxtColor = Color.parseColor("#FF171E24");   
    int TEXT_COLOR = Color.parseColor("#82CAFD");
    int TEXT_COLOR_2 = Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF");
    int BTN_COLOR = Color.parseColor("#1C262D");
    int MENU_BG_COLOR = Color.parseColor("#FF1C1C1C"); //#AARRGGBB
    int MENU_FEATURE_BG_COLOR = Color.par
....
```

I apologize in advance if you think my question is irrelevant.

Help me on this.